# Create a primary partition on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have windows 7 installed.

On the moment i have the following partitions on 1 hard disk: (300 GB)

C: (Windows) (Primary, System, Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Active) 100 GB

D: (Data) (Logical) 100 GB

E: (System Reserved created after Boot repair) (primary, system) 100 MB

Now i want to create a new primary partition on this disk, because i have +/- 100 GB left, for a new OS.
However when trying to make a new partition, it makes it a Logical partition, not Primary.
How to make it primary...?

Comment: How big is your hard drive?

Comment: As it says: '...on 1 hard disk: (300 GB)'

Comment: Whoops! Missed that.  What OS are you trying to install?

Comment: Would it matter? Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a second primary disk, you'll need to use a partitioning tool to hide the first primary disk. After the second installation, you can then unhide the first one.

Rather than play this game of hiding and unhiding partitions, it's best to use a boot manager 
to take care of the whole thing. Some such products are :

[BootIt NG](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-next-generation.htm) ($34.95)
Support of over 200 primary partitions (if desired). I've used it and it's probably the best.

[GAG](http://gag.sourceforge.net/) (initials, in spanish, of Graphical Boot Manager) (open-source)
Allows boot of up to 9 different operating systems installed in primary and extended partitions. Never used it.

[Partition Commander 11](http://www.avanquest.com/USA/software/partition-commander-11-126553?meta=pc-utilities&cat=disk-management-software&sub=hard-disk-software) ($49.95)
No info on maximum partitions number. I've used it a long time ago and it worked then pretty well.

[Norton PartitionMagic 8.0](http://www.symantec.com/norton/partitionmagic) ($69.95)
Otherwise called BootMagic, no info on maximum partitions number, and seems to only support partitions up to 300GB. Never used it, and I usually stay away from Norton products.

Warning: Before playing with partitions, take great care with your backups.

Answer (score 0):

The new OS should create the partition for you if the free space hasn't already been partition.  That would be the easiest way.

Comment: yeah i get that but it won't. running Windows 7 RTM build 7600.

Answer (score 0):

As you are allowed at least 3 primary partitions, my guess is that your free space is in that one logical partition.  Have a look at the color coding, and the words Primary and Logical in your graphic.

If this is the case there is no way of creating another primary without deleting the Logical drive and starting again.  Oh, yes there are 3rd party utilities to reclaim disk space.

Comment: No, i already tried this. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a couple of options. The built in 'DISKPART' utility is surpirisingly powerful. You run it from an administrative command line. 
[DISKPART](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)

Another solution could be to use the built in 'Disk Managment' console snap-in, which is similar to diskpart but with a GUI. [Disk Management Snap-In](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-and-format-a-hard-disk-partition)

Both can perform the same functions, though i prefer the command line DiskPart. If neither soltion will work for you, a boot disk with older disk utilities may be your best bet.

In any case, I would avoid anything you have to pay for. There are plenty of free options outh there, and they all perform the same.